# Trying to read multiple modes into a vector and then print them out c++

Tags: c++, vector

Basically I am trying to find the mode in a vector for example if the vector is 1 1 1, it just returns no mode. also it needs to be able to read up to two possible modes prof said not to worry about more than 2 modes. Any suggestions would be very helpful.
Also the void calcMode is part of it it won't let me add it to the code i don't know how to change it.

```
void calcMode(vector <double> const& vec)
{
    int counter = 1;
    int max = 0;
    vector<double> mode;
    for (int pass = 0; pass < vec.size() - 1; pass++)
        {
            if (vec[pass] == vec[pass + 1])
            {
                counter++;
                // If they are the same number add it to the mode vector
                if (counter > max)
                {
                    mode.clear();
                    max = counter;
                    mode.push_back(vec[pass]);
                }
                // if it is greater clear the vector and assign it the new value
                else if (counter == max)
                {
                    mode.push_back(vec[pass]);
                }

            }
            else
                counter = 1; // reset counter.
        }
    // print out the freq and the mode(s)
    cout << mode.size() << endl;
    cout << "Mode: " << setw(25) << setprecision(3);

    cout << setw(25) << setprecision(3);

    if (vec.size() == 1)
    {
        cout << "Freq = " << counter << endl;
        cout << vec[0] << endl;
    }
    else if (vec.size() == 2)
    {
        cout << "Freq = " << counter << endl;
        cout << vec[0] << vec[1] << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "No mode" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Quick hack: `std::map<int, int> freq;` With this little beauty you can `freq[vec[index]]++;` to get a frequency count of all elements in the `vector`. Then just walk through `freq` looking for the highest (or two highest) counts. Function's done in 5-6 lines of code.

Comment: Other than that, pick one problem and focus the question on that one problem. Otherwise you're going to collect down votes, close votes, and fragmented answers. None of that is worth your time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i've tried your method it counts the highest values but how do i display the highest ones? Like if it's 20 20 10 11 the freq would be 2 but how do I printout 20?

Comment: [`std::max_element` will find the highest count](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) but it looks like I lied about the 5-6 lines of code. You'll have to build a comparator function that compares the `second` in the pairs in the `map`.

Comment: ON second thought give me a minute. I'll write this up.

Comment: Took a bit longer. Waffled over `for` loop vs `for_each`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using standard library where possible and where it makes sense.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

// comparator function. When you compare two std::pair, you get both sides 
// in the compare. We only want the value side, so we define a function to 
// only test the value side.  
static bool comp(std::pair<unsigned,unsigned> lhs,
                 std::pair<unsigned,unsigned> rhs)
{
    return (lhs.second < rhs.second);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector <double> const& vec {0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 0, 1, 3};
    std::map<double, int> freq;

    // build frequency count
    for (double val:vec) 
    {
        freq[val]++;
    }
    // or 
    //std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&freq](double val){ freq[val]++; });
    // not sure if using for_each makes sense here. I don't think we get much

    // find highest frequency
    std::map<double, int>::iterator found = std::max_element(freq.begin(),
                                                             freq.end(),
                                                             comp);
    // cache what we found so we have it later
    std::pair<double, int> mode = *found;
    std::cout << found->first << " freq: "  << found->second << '\n';
    // remove so we don't find again
    freq.erase(found);

    // look for next highest frequency
    found = std::max_element(freq.begin(), freq.end(), comp);
    // test for same frequency
    if (mode.second == found->second)
    {
        std::cout << found->first << " freq: "  << found->second << '\n';
    }
}
```

[`std::max_element` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)

[`std::for_each` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each)